# Ticket To Ride Netherlands - Loans

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I am out of coins. I need 2 Euros to acquire my next route. Loans are 5 Euros. Do I get 3 Euros in change? My competitor say the rules do not specify change, so I don't. I say change is logical, so I do.

Answer (score 8):

You do not get "change". Loan cards are simply a penalty for playing a route that you can't afford to play. The loan is not a loan for 5 Euros, rather it is simply a card that counts as minus 5 points at the end of the game. The rules don't distinguish between being only 1 toll token short of playing a route or being short more than that... if you are short at all then you get -5 points at the end of the game. The loan card is just the reminder for that point loss.

From [the rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/720120-T2RMC4-Rules-EN-2019.pdf):

> If a player doesn’t have enough Bridge Toll Tokens left to
> pay for the cost of a route, that player must take a single
> Loan card from the bank when claiming that route, and
> place it face up in front of him for the rest of the game.
> The player pays no Tokens (even if he could have made
> a partial payment), and can never reimburse this Loan.